# cp: cannot create regular file '/home/Documents': Permission denied

Tags: linux, permission-denied, cp

I am learning linux CLI, I created a file `app.txt` in `home` directory. Now I am copying it through CLI to `Documents` and it is showing me an error:

```
cp: cannot create regular file '/home/Documents': Permission denied
```

P.S (I have checked `whoami` and it is showing `zain` which is my root)

Can anyone confirm what is wrong with it ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Try asking on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: Your home directory is probably `/home/zain`, so you should copy to `/home/zain/Documents`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume you attempted to copy `app.txt` while in your `home` directory.

Since your root directory is `zain`, specifying `/home/Documents` as the destination path will result in an error as the CLI will go back to `zain` directory (due to `/`) and then look for the `home` directory, which is absent under it.

Instead, you just need to specify `Documents` as the destination path as follows. Again, I am assuming you are still in your `home` directory.

```sh
cp app.txt Documents
```

Answer (score 2):

give 777 (readable, writable and executable) permissions to file or directory

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /folder-location
```